# GitHub Versioning - Organizing Structure

Tags: github, versioning, branching, semantic-versioning, release

I am making a JS library that creates graphs and charts using canvas. I have hosted it on GitHub as a public repository.

So after looking at some other related questions, I have figured out two solutions to keep active releases separate.

**Method 1**:

- The master branch is named `dev`.

  - All work happens in this branch
- Once a release is ready, a new branch is made.

  - Its name would be `Version {Major.Minor.HotFix}`

**Method 2**:

- The the master branch is named `Version {Latest Version Number}`
- There is a dev branch.
- Once a new version is ready, the master branch is branched off and the dev branch is merged into the master branch and renamed. Then the work for the next version starts again on the dev branch.

Which one would you recommend? Which one will be clearer to contributors/users?

I hope I am clear, if not, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "active releases"? Is that releases that are being used in other projects? Or releases that receive new feature updates? Or something else?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I mean releases that people may still be using or critical bug fixes may still happen on. Not the latest but still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to have much fun renaming branches like that.

Why not stay simple?  `master` branch is your root.  Create branches off it for your features or releases (call it, say, `dev`), then you can branch off `dev` with your `feature` branches.  As features are developed and good, you PR/merge them back into `dev`.  When you got everything working in `dev`, PR/merge `dev` into `master` and tag `master` with your release number.

You continue to work in `dev`, creating new identified `feature` branches (by identified, I mean you'd create a branch off dev called `feature/adding-pie-chart` or something similar.  Get the pie chart working in that branch, then PR/merge it back to `dev`.  Lather, rinse, repeat.  If you get new contributors, they would branch off `dev`, do their do, then PR it back to `dev` where you'd have a chance to review.

Comment: Ok so I think this is what I needed. Please let me know if my understanding of tags is correct. Once I tag the master branch as the release number (version number), people can still go back to the old versions right?

Comment: @TalinTheDev, Yes. a tag gives a user-friendly name to a particular commit. The tag remains with that commit, even when more changes are added to the branch(es) that the commit is a part of.

Comment: So, basically, tags are read-only branches... without being branches? Oof

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is [trunk-based development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) with [branch-for-release](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/). This is a well-known concept. Even if an individual developer doesn't know it, there are plenty of resources for understanding it and working through any problems.

Method 2 is, as far as I know, not a widely used pattern. The renaming of branches is unexpected and could lead to confusion.

Given these two options, I would recommend Method 1.

Comment: Yes, I thought of method 1 first but I wasn't sure. Thanks anyways! I accepted Mike's answer because he answered first but your answer helped me decide too.

Comment: @TalinTheDev if it helped you too, you can upvote (this doesn't change naything to your answer selection)

Comment: I would, but I only have 13 rep... Sorry! If you upvote, my question, I can upvote yours!